# fetching records with same random word in specified column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have following data in table,

```
id               Description              Category
1      I  am Desc with printer            main category
2      I am desc with test                 test category  
3          new printer desc                third category  
4        new test category                  printer category
```

and So on....

I want to find count having same word(Which can be anything like printer but not predefined) in their description field.
For ex Output should be:

```
Total      Word which is same
  2         printer
  2          test
```

I tried using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html example with boolean option but its not giving desired output.

Here is example I given is printer which can be anything.
I dont want to specify this word in query anywhere because it can be anything.
only description having same words anywhere should be in output.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Description like '%printer%',1,0)) AS Printer,SUM(IF(Description like '%test%',1,0)) AS Test FROM `yourTable`
```

this might be help :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary of all the words in the descriptions

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = "SELECT description FROM tableName";

foreach($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result){
    foreach (explode(' ',$result['description']) as $word){
        $words[] = $word;
    }   
}
```

Count the duplicate values in the array using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), optionally sort it descending

```
$wordCount = array_count_values($words);
arsort($wordCount);
```

Then filter the array to eliminate the words that occur just once using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filteredWordCount = array_filter($wordCount, function($value){
    return $value!=1;
});
```

this should give you an array that has the words themselves as indexes and the number of occurrences as values.

Iterate over the array and run a `COUNT` query

```
foreach($filteredWordCount as $word=>$value){
    $countSQL = 'select COUNT(*) as rowCount from tableName where description like "%' . $word . '%" ';
    $res = $dbh->query($countSQL, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $count[$word] = $res->fetch()['rowCount'];
}
```

Sort the array on the values, like before, and print it out

```
arsort($count);
print_r($count);
```

If you need a condition on the number of rows, for example, return only words that appear in more than 5 records you can adjust the query like this

```
foreach($filteredWordCount as $word=>$value){
    $countSQL = 'select COUNT(*) as rowCount from domains where description like "%' . $word . '%" HAVING rowCount > 5';
    $res = $dbh->query($countSQL, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $c = $res->fetch()['rowCount'];

    if (isset($c)){
        $count[$word] = $c;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection, it should be using parameterized queries.